# Why is my node.js not returning true in the return true statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using VS code and I am wondering why the return true command does not print anything in my terminal while the console.log(map[arr2[j]]) can return true in my terminal. Is it something with node or my terminal? How can I get it to return true in my VS code terminal?

```js
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = ["r", "z", "y", "a"];
function checkIfItemsMatch (arr1, arr2) {
    // Create map object
    let map = {};
    // Loop through first array 
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        // if the property does not yet exist in the object, add it and set its value to true
        if (!map[arr1[i]]) {
            let item = arr1[i];
            map[item] = true;
        }
    }
    // Loop through second array
    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        // check to see if any items in second array is included in the map object. If yes, return true otherwise, false
        if (map[arr2[j]]) {
            console.log("map[arr2[j]] =" , map[arr2[j]])
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false
}

const result = checkIfItemsMatch(array1, array2);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You haven't written your code to log the result of the function. If would log it if you used `console.log(checkIfItemsMatch(array1,array2));`

Comment: Can you tell us more specific where you expect what value? I changed your code so we can execute it here. Maybe tell us what you expect in the first console.log to return and in the second (result) one.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag Editing code  to make it a a stack snippet was good. Inserting `console.log(result)` at the end to show it on the console was the same answer prepared and posted by @Nate, presumably in response to the original unedited code posted by the OP.

Comment: Justin, could you please confirm that @Nate 's answer is correct -  the return value isn't shown on the terminal because it wasn't logged on the terminal in code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `return true` statement will not print anything to your terminal. This line simply tells the function to return with the value equal to true. If you want the return value to be printed in your terminal, you should modify your last line to be:

`console.log(checkIfItemsMatch(array1, array2));`